# Reload a page on button click

Tags: angular, ionic2

Is there a way to reload a page on button click?

```
<button ion-button (click)="reload()"></button>
 <ion-row *ngFor="let file of MyAudioFiles let i = index  ">{{file.name}}</ion-row>

MyAudioFiles: any[] = [];

reload(){
  // what should I write to reload the current page on button click in ionic2 
}

  ListAudioFiles() {
        console.log("list obj", obj);
        File.listDir(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, 'Vanan/Audios').then(
            (allFiles) => {
                // do something

                console.log("we have audio files", allFiles);
                console.log("we have audio files", allFiles.length);
                for (var i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++) {
                    this.MyAudioFiles.push({
                        audio: allFiles[i],
                        status: false,

                    });
                    console.log(this.MyAudioFiles);
                }
```

Consider I have a list and I delete 1 item in that list. Delete is executed successfully, but, in UI, item count not gets decreased. If I move back a page and again come back to list page, then I am able to see changes in my list.

Comment: Maybe try `window.location.reload()`?

Comment: reload as in the data? you can simply call whatever functions you call in `ngOnInit` or `ionViewDidLoad`..

Comment: how are you loading the list the first time? can you put that code?

Comment: i guess you want to reload the data after delete one of the items, try call the service once again to refresh the data at the delete event.

Comment: Please paste all the relevant code in your question. Like, where is the count displayed? Where is the data loaded in typescript? Where is your delete made?

Comment: i am also facing a similar kind of issue , as i am clicking on the button , i want my page to get refreshed , but it's just not happening , instead i need to use this.navCtrl.push(myPageThatIwantToBeReloaded, {}); 
 but it creates an issue on back press, it goes to same screen again

Comment: After deletion, why not call the method that retrieves the `myAudioFiles`, meaning execute the method `ListAudioFiles`, which updates the list?

Comment: i tried to call the function 'ListAudioFiles' the whole object gets displayed twice @AJT_82

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the data asnycron via Observables. This way you don't need to refresh the app, just put in the new value into the observable-stream  and it will change automaticly. Put a nice change-effect style on the counter, so the user can see, that the counter is changed.

Comment: could some one give some sample

Answer (score 0):

Since you just want to update your array `MyAudioFiles`, there is no need to refresh the whole component, you just update the list after deletion.

For this, make some changes, get rid of declaring your your array as `any`. Create an interface, which you can cast your response to and use `map` instead of iterating the response.

So the interface could be:

```ts
export interface AudioFile {
  audio: string;
  status: boolean;
}
```

And where you retrieve this data, use map:

```ts
listDir(...) {
  .....
  .toPromise()
  .then(res => res.json().map((x: any) => <AudioFile>{audio: x, status: false})
}
```

and then in your component, declare `MyAudioFiles` of type `AudioFile[]`

```ts
MyAudioFiles: AudioFile[] = [];
```

and your method to retrieve AudioFiles:

```ts
ListAudioFiles() {
  File.listDir(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, 'Vanan/Audios')
     .then(data => {
        this.MyAudioFiles = data;
     });
}
```

Now when you delete something, you just calls `ListAudioFiles` again, which updates that list, so something like this:

```ts
delete() {
  File.delete(....)
    .then(res => {
       console.log(res);
       this.ListAudioFiles(); // add this!
    });
}
```

Hope this helps! :)